# Breadcrumbs and Page title in same div module

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm trying to make the breadrumbs module to display also the page title but with no luck.

All i want is breadcrumbs and page title (of an article or menu) to display in same div!

Example here:
http://www.astemplates.com/itempreview/315

For example breadcrumbs float left and page title float right in same div!

---

I tried your advice but i recieve fatal error.

I did override the breadcrumbs module the default.php file and before  i put a div with the php that you wrote!

Here it is:

```
<?php
    defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::_('bootstrap.tooltip');

?>

<div class="title<?php echo JSite::getMenu()->getItem(&JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->tree[0])->title; ?>">

</div>

<ul class="breadcrumb<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
    <?php
    if ($params->get('showHere', 1))
    {
        echo '<li class="active">' . JText::_('MOD_BREADCRUMBS_HERE') . '&#160;</li>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<li class="active"><span class="divider icon-location"></span></li>';
    }
```

Whay i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: If you want to add additional information, edit your question, don't add more questions as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looder has reason JSite it's deprecated use

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

echo $app->getMenu()->getItem($app->getMenu()->getActive()->tree[0])->title;
```

Now it works! (tested in a Joomla! 3.3.6)

But your html it's not valid if you want to show the breadcrumbs to the left and the page title to the right... must be something like:

```
<div class = "breadcrumbs<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
<?php if ($params->get('showHere', 1))
{
    echo '<span class="showHere">' .JText::_('MOD_BREADCRUMBS_HERE').'</span>';
}

// Get rid of duplicated entries on trail including home page when using multilanguage
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    if ($i == 1 && !empty($list[$i]->link) && !empty($list[$i - 1]->link) && $list[$i]->link == $list[$i - 1]->link)
    {
        unset($list[$i]);
    }
}

// Find last and penultimate items in breadcrumbs list
end($list);
$last_item_key = key($list);
prev($list);
$penult_item_key = key($list);

// Generate the trail
foreach ($list as $key => $item) :
// Make a link if not the last item in the breadcrumbs
$show_last = $params->get('showLast', 1);
if ($key != $last_item_key)
{
    // Render all but last item - along with separator
    if (!empty($item->link))
    {
        echo '<a href="' . $item->link . '" class="pathway">' . $item->name . '</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<span>' . $item->name . '</span>';
    }

    if (($key != $penult_item_key) || $show_last)
    {
        echo ' '.$separator.' ';
    }

}
elseif ($show_last)
{
    // Render last item if reqd.
    echo '<span>' . $item->name . '</span>';
}
endforeach; ?>

<div style="float:right;"><?php echo JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getItem(JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive()->tree[0])->title; ?></div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can override the breadcrumbs module from your template adding some html and styles to insert a right floating div and print inside the menu title with

```
<?php echo JSite::getMenu()->getItem(&JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->tree[0])->title; ?>
```

Comment: `JSite::getMenu()` is deprecated and has been for a long time. If you want to get the active menu item, see here: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page